# How can I get a SQL dump of a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dump

How can I get a SQL dump of a SQL Server 2008 database? That is, a .sql file with inserts to regenerate the data in another database, much like mysqldump.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From SQL Server Management Studio you can use the Generate Scripts command in the Tasks item of the right-click menu on the target database. From here you generate scripts for the structure and data and SPs etc: make sure 'Script Data' is set to True in the scripting options to get the inserts.

Comment: In generate scripts, you need to press "advanced" and change the option "Types of data script" to "Schema and data" to have also the inserts

Comment: the advanced button needed is under the 'set scripting options' tab/page

Answer (score 11):

Not finding what I needed (scriptable tool dumping SQL statements), I have created a tool called SQL Server Dump which is inspired by mysqldump, but for SQL Server. You will find it on [github](https://github.com/daniel-jann/sqlserverdump/)

Comment: +1 for a useful tool. You are probably not the first one to write that, but it's available and working

Answer (score 8):

I had a hard time finding the 'Script Data' option mentioned in stuartd's answer on SQL Server 2008 R2.  I found the 'Types of data to script' option and changed it to 'Schema and Data' and that did the trick