# Backup entire database using SQL command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The question is easy: is there a commant to backup an entire SqlServer database to a `.sql` file?

I developed a web application and now I need a button that permits to download a `.sql` file with all the data on the server.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest regular backup. Please read this MSDN entry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx. Do you really need all data in *.sql file in text format?

Comment: Possible duplicate with [How can I get a SQL dump of a SQL Server 2008 database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391110/how-can-i-get-a-sql-dump-of-a-sql-server-2008-database)

Comment: are you using a mysql ?

Comment: No, OP wants *with all the data on the server*, and script generator produce code to create/alter objects.

Comment: The question is easy, the answer is also easy. `N O`

Comment: There is no such tool inside SQL Server. But you could use this one [SQL Server Dump](http://sqlserverdump.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys. Maybe I should create the dump manually..table for table.. not so funny.
I will give a chance to the tool suggested by @gofr1